# Saving and restoring the full state of a React app

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a VSCode extension using React. When the tab loses focus, VSCode shuts down the WebView and only reloads it when the tab gets focus again. The app fully reloads from the start.

VSCode already provides  a way to save arbitrary state object and then get it back when restoring the WebView.
What remains is to serialize the full state of the React app (the whole React DOM, states etc) into a simple JSON-like object.

How can I serialize the full state of the React app and then reload it?

I know that React has some features like Server-Side Rendering - maybe they can be used to serialize DOM and state?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish that, you need some kind of **global state** object, which holds all the state data that you want to preserve. You can then save and restore this object using the VSCode API you mentioned.

There are several ways to do that and different 3rd-party libraries for this purpose. Here I will outline some of the options.

#### Context API

[Context](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/createcontext) API is built into React. You need to create an instance and wrap your app with a context provider. Then you can access the state in your child components with [useContext](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usecontext).

Here's an example of how you would use it to store some user and page data, as well as control some textarea field in a child component, which would normally be a local state.

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState("");
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState("home");
  // etc.

  // this is your global state object that you can then save using VSCode magic
  const globalState = { user, setUser, /* etc. */ };

  return (
    <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={globalState}>
      <Child />
    </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

...

const Child = () => {
  const { textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue } = useContext(GlobalStateContext);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTextAreaValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <textarea value={textAreaValue} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}
```

Of course, this will be cumbersome if you have a lot of state data to manage.  Furthermore, whenever any field in the context changes, **all components using it will re-render**. This could cause performance issues, so this solution does not scale well. It should be fine for a simple application though.

#### Custom store hook

Another solution would be to use a global store functionality. You could write a custom hook for that and then use it like this:

```
const Child = () => {
  const { textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue } = useStore("textarea");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTextAreaValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <textarea value={textAreaValue} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}
```

I won't provide a full example of how to implement this for brevity, but here is [one guide](https://medium.com/craftsmenltd/implementing-a-global-store-using-react-context-and-hook-patterns-part-1-233368f0b2df) that could be useful.

#### 3rd-party library

There are also 3rd-party libraries that implement the global store functionality. A popular choice is Redux, although I personally wouldn't recommend it if you haven't used it before, due to its verbosity and somewhat of a learning curve. Other options include [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/), [react-hooks-global-state](https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-global-state) and [ReactN](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn).